# Posting links to questions on Hacker News and programming - Reddit

Tags: discussion, views

Is it ethical, reasonable, fruitful and/or Ok to post links to your SO questions on sites like Hacker News and programming - Reddit, to get more views by programmers and thus more chances to get answer (quickly)? Also, Will It be taken positively or a greedy and desperate attempt to get answer quickly ?

Comment: Why wouldn't it be? We have explicit share buttons for Twitter and Google+.

Comment: The problem I see is that most SO questions I see posted on reddit and HN aren't good at all for SO. They're often asking for opinions or comparisons or simply very broad and do very well on SO just because they're publicized.

Comment: @Bart Yes but there is more chances to get answers from sites like these.

Comment: I'm saying that there is no problem because you're explicitly encouraged to do so (for example through the buttons I mentioned).

Answer (score 10):

Absolutely. StackOverflow actively encourages such behaviour by offering you badges for bringing in visitors too!

See the [Announcer](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/260/announcer), [Booster](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/261/booster) and [Publicist](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/262/publicist) badges; just make sure you use the link provided to you using the `link` target underneath a question or answer, or use the social sharing buttons that appear below  and/or besides posts.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a matter of ethics, as long as you're not doing mass flooding.

Reddit is designed for posting links to special and interesting resources. So, if you question is very interesting, why not? But, if your question have no answers and low number of visits, this is propably not the case and you'll get no visits from Reddit anyway.

So, as for me, it makes sense for interesting questions with high number of views and no answers or little helping answers. Such questions ARE interesting, but there's lack of experts who could answer it. Such portals could attract some experts to StackOverflow.

But, if there's no interest in your question, they'll be ignored on Redding in the same way. You'll be better off publishing links on your blogs, at least you'll get some bonus to position in google search (Digg's etc. are setting `nofollow` attribute to prevent SEO misuse).

Answer (score 1):

As long as you add "/1228" to the end of these links, its perfectly acceptable.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I'll be sure to do this with all the Programmers SE and Super User questions I share.

Comment: What does adding "/1228" means?

Comment: @UmerHayat: It's his user id. If enough people visit the question/answer via that link he'll get a nice badge.

Comment: @Won't: You meant to write `/298479`, didn't you? :P